# Printing to text area

Tags: javascript, html

How do I preset the values in the table using Javascript?

```
<u><h1>Rabbits vs Foxes Population Model</h1></u>
    <form name = "Rabbits">
    <table border = "3">
    <tr><td>No. of Rabbits</td><td><center><input type="number" id="no_rabbits" /></center></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Death Rates</td><td><center><input type="number" id="death" /></center></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Birth Rates</td><td><center><input type="number" id="birth" /></center></td></tr>
    <tr><td>No. of Foxes</td><td><center><input type="number" id="foxes" /></center></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Rabbit Conditions</td><td> Normal <input type="radio" name="condition" value="normal"> Cold <input type="radio" name="condition" value="cold"> Fires <input type="radio" name="condition" value="fires">Excellent <input type="radio" name="condition" value="excellent"></td></tr>
    <tr><td> Graph the Rabbits</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="graph" value="answer"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button type = "button" onclick="addyear()"> One Year Passes </button></td><td>  </td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Preset what values from what source? Might be worthwhile spending a few minutes reading through [ask] then update question with all relevant details

Comment: oh sorry, this is my first question. If I have the values set in within the javascript.

Comment: Three of the `<input>` elements at `javascript` at Question each have a `.value` set. `document.getElementById("no_rabbits").value = "abc`;

Comment: last comment is not very informative. If you want help here and expect others to put in time creating quality answers then you need to put in the effort and time to ask quality questions that are clear and concise

Answer (score 1):

You can either set the value when declaring the inputs (eg: `<input type="number" id="no_rabbits" value="23"/>`) or do it with javascript and target the inputs using the id of each and simply set the value. Note that I also altered your h1 structure - much better to apply a css rule to the h1 than have the `<u>` OUTSIDE of the h1. Not sure what the value for each is - just set it to 1 - 4 to demonsstrate. Also the addYear function is not declared and therefore throwing an error on the click. I also removed the `<center>` tags - they are no longer supported and you should use CSS to apply centering CSS rules for the desired td's.

Another thing - even though these inputs are set to type = "number" they will still return a string - so you will need to parse them (using parseInt or parseFloat) to get a number for calculations.

```js
document.getElementById('no_rabbits').value="1";
document.getElementById('death').value="2";
document.getElementById('birth').value="3";
document.getElementById('foxes').value="4";
```

```css
h1{text-decoration: underline}
```

```html
<h1>Rabbits vs Foxes Population Model</h1>
    <form name = "Rabbits">
    <table border = "3">
    <tr><td>No. of Rabbits</td><td><input type="number" id="no_rabbits" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Death Rates</td><td><input type="number" id="death" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Birth Rates</td><td><input type="number" id="birth" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>No. of Foxes</td><td><input type="number" id="foxes" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Rabbit Conditions</td><td> Normal <input type="radio" name="condition" value="normal"> Cold <input type="radio" name="condition" value="cold"> Fires <input type="radio" name="condition" value="fires">Excellent <input type="radio" name="condition" value="excellent"></td></tr>
    <tr><td> Graph the Rabbits</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="graph" value="answer"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button type = "button" onclick="addyear()"> One Year Passes </button></td><td>  </td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: oh i see now, thank you!

Comment: you are welcome - happy to help. Check my answer out - i have edited since you looked at it last. If this answer was helpful for you please check the "accept" checkbox so that other users can see that there is a solution for it. Cheers Gav.